# Why am I getting an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I while ago I migrated to Rails 4 but initially I used the "protected_attributes" gem.

Now, I've removed that gem, and I think I'm using strong parameters correctly, but I'm getting the following error. Why?

```
From: /Users/steven/Dropbox/Testivate/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb @ line 21 CategoriesController#create:

    20: def create
 => 21:   binding.pry_remote
    22:   @category = Category.new(params[:category]).permit(:name)
    23:   flash[:notice] = "Category was successfully created." if @category.save
    24:   respond_with(@category)
    25: end

[1] pry(#<CategoriesController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "category"=>{"name"=>"Clothes"},
 "commit"=>"Create Category",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"categories"}
[2] pry(#<CategoriesController>)> @category = Category.new(params[:category]).permit(:name)
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
from /Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
[3] pry(#<CategoriesController>)>
```

I have commented out the `config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer` statement in `development.rb` and I have no `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` statement in my `application.rb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
@category = Category.new(params.require(:category).permit(:name))
```

Comment: @steven_noble simply because that's how strong params work. You need to manually 'require' specific params key and permit attributes from it.

Comment: Moreover, this code should not be in your create method. You should call a private method with permitted attributes for Category in a private method in a before action.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case of using Rails **Strong Parameters**. Imagine, you have a **Cuisine** Model, and it has a **Name**, **A Brief Description** and an **Associated Pic**. So, your Cuisine Controller will have its **Strong Parameter** used this way.

```
class CuisineController < ApplicationController
    #method for strong parameters
    def required-fields-for-cuisine-form
        params.require(:cuisine).permit(:name, :brief-description, :associated-pic)    
    end

    #method for Form for Creating a Cuisine Record
    def create_cuisine
        @cuisine = Cuisine.new(required-fields-for-cuisine-form)
        if @cuisine.save
            flash[:success] = "Your cuisine has been saved."
            redirect_to cuisine_path(@cuisine)
        end
    end
```

This **Github** **READ ME** from the **Rails Team** shows how you could use **Strong Parameters**:
https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters